# how can to calculate jpeg2000 file header size in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, header, image-compression, jpeg2000

I want to know size of header in an image in jpeg2000 format. how can I find out this header?

I want to calculate pure size of image.jp2 in hard disk without the size of header.

I use `iminfo` to find some information in matlab about image, but I don't know that can I find the header size of the image from this?

Actually I compress an image with jpeg2000 and I want to calculate rate of compression without header size.

please help me.

Comment: The JPEG2k header is pretty small, I doubt it will affect your compression ratio too much. In both jpeg2k files I checked its 12+20+345=377 bytes.

Comment: can you explain me how ?thank you very much

Comment: I opened it in a hex editor and added up the chunk sizes. See [here](http://www.file-recovery.com/jp2-signature-format.htm). If you need a hex editor I like HxD.

Comment: More detailed description of jpeg2k layout [here](https://github.com/plroit/Skyreach/wiki/Introduction-to-JPEG2000-Structure-and-Layout)

Comment: can you tell me the heaer size of lena 512*512*8 compressed with jpeg2000 by compression ratio 8? Is it like that image you said befor?377 bytes

Answer (score 1):

J2K files have 4 compulsory top-level boxes. They are

- JPEG 2000 signature box
- File Type box
- JP2 Header box
- Contiguous Codestream box

Each box is preceded by 4 byte marker and 4 byte size value. So in MATLAB it should be something like this

```
fname='C:\Users\admin\Documents\MATLAB\SO\Jpeg2k\balloon.jp2';
fid = fopen(fname);
headerMark = uint8('jp2h');
matchCnt = 1;

ch = fread(fid,1,'*uint8');
matchCnt = matchCnt+isequal(headerMark(1),ch);

while matchCnt < 5 && ~feof(fid)
    ch = fread(fid,1,'*uint8');
    matchCnt = matchCnt+isequal(headerMark(matchCnt),ch);
end
if matchCnt == 5
    fseek(fid,ftell(fid)-8,'bof');
    sizeBytes = fread(fid,4,'*uint8');
    sizeVal = arrayfun(@(x,y) bitshift(x,y,32), uint32(sizeBytes), [3:-1:0]');
    sizeVal = bitor(bitor(bitor(sizeVal(1),sizeVal(2)),sizeVal(3)),sizeVal(4));
end
fclose(fid);
```

I don't know what is you final task (getting header size seems to be halfway) but I recommend to see the quickstart [guide](https://github.com/plroit/Skyreach/wiki/Introduction-to-JPEG2000-Structure-and-Layout) for JPEG2000, [JPEG2000 validator](https://github.com/openpreserve/jpylyzer) (written in python) and the validator [overview](http://openpreservation.org/blog/2011/12/14/prototype-jp2-validator-and-properties-extractor/).